# Show $y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} x^k$ satisfies $ye^{-y} = x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, random-graphs

My question is literally the title:

> Show $y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} x^k$ satisfies $ye^{-y} = x$.

---

Here's a little motivation for the question. If you don't care about motivation, then ignore what follows!

Considering Erdos-Renyi random graphs, in the supercritical case $p = c/n$ with $c > 1$, and consider the size of the giant component. We can show (eg Grimmett, Probability on Graphs, Theorem 11.1) that the size is $\theta(p) n$, where $\theta(p) \equiv \theta(c)$ is the survival probability for a Poisson$(c)$ branching process ($p = c/n$), and this satisfies
$$ 1 - \theta(c) = \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} (ce^{-c})^k.$$
Moreover, one can also show (eg, Frieze-Karonski, Introduction to Random Graphs, Theorem 2.14) that $\theta(c) = 1 - c'/c$, where $c'$ is the *conjugate* of $c$, ie for $c>1$ it is the solution $c' < 1$ of $c'e^{-c'} = c e^{-c}$. Combining these two formulae, we obtain (cancelling the $1/c$ factor)
$$ c' = \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!} (ce^{-c})^k.$$
In my general statement at the top, I've just let $y = c'$ and $x = ce^{-c}$ for notational convenience.

---

Try as I might, I haven't been able to come up with any way of justifying the equality, however -- other than, of course, proving the two results on the size of the giant separately, then equating. One would hope that there's a way of showing it directly -- after all, it's not exactly an ugly expression: after not very long it becomes basically geometric; I tried on Matlab and with $c = 3$ I get machine precision after only $40$ terms in the sum. (My PhD supervisor has had a look at it too, but she wasn't able to work it out either!)

Comment: What happens if you try to compute the Taylor series for $y$ (using implicit differentiation) around $x=0$?  Using Stirling's approximation, it looks like you've got a reasonably convergent power series around $x=0$.

Comment: This is $y=W(-x)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Do you mean differentiate with respect to $x$ to get $(y' - yy')e^{-y} = 1$, ie $(1 - y)y' e^{-y} = 1$? I don't really see how this helps: yes we can try differentiating under the sum, but there still $(sum)^{-(sum)'}$ which is awkward.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah, I saw that when looking up related questions. I can't see any explicit formulation of the Lambert W function -- in fact, one person said "use the Lambert W function, as an explicit solution is very complicated" (or something to that effect). Above I've given an explicit formula in the form of a power series with very nice coefficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial way to view this identity with generating functions.

The number of *labelled* *unrooted* trees with vertex set $[n]:=\{1, \ldots, n\}$ is $n^{n-2}$ (Cayley's formula). So the number of *rooted* trees is $\alpha_n := n\cdot n^{n-2} = n^{n-1}$. So $y = T(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_n}{n!} x^n$ is the (exponential) generating function for the sequence $\alpha_n$, of the number of rooted trees.

The identity you want can be written 
$$
T(x) = x \cdot e^{T(x)} = x \left(1+ T(x) + T^2(x)/2!+T^3(x)/3!+\ldots \right).
$$

So you want to show that the coefficient by $x^n/n!$ on the right hand side is also $\alpha_n$. Obviously, $\alpha_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_n(k)$, where $\alpha_n(k)$ is the number of rooted trees where the root has degree $k$ ($\alpha_n(k) = 0$ for $k \geq n$).

The term $x \cdot T^k(x)/k!$ is the generating function for the number of ordered pairs of $(v, F_k)$ where $v$ is a single vertex and $F_k$ is an unordered $k$-tuple of disjoint rooted trees. Now there is a natural bijection between such a pair and rooted trees (connect single vertex (the new root) with each root in $k$-tuple) where the root has degree $k$. In particular, the coefficient in front of $x^n/n!$ in $x \cdot T^k(x)/k!$ is the number of rooted trees on $n$ vertices where the root has degree $k$. That is, the coefficient is $\alpha_n(k)$.

Comment: Superb, thanks! Could you explain a little further why the term $X \cdot T^k(x)/k!$ is the generating function you've claimed? In the pair $(v,F_k)$, I presume $F_k$ can be a $k$-tuple of trees of any size? But then what if $v$ is in one of these trees but not the root, and adding the edge you suggested creates a cycle?

Comment: See [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf) for a note on products of generating functions. In particular, the product $T^k(x)$ is the exponential generating function for an ordered $k$-tuple of rooted trees. So $T^k(x)/k!$ is the exponential generating function for number of forest of $k$ trees.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. Probably being slow (10pm makes me like that!), but I don't see why multiplying by $x$ then adds in $v$. Informally, the division by $k!$ changes $F_k$ from ordered to **un**ordered, correct?

Comment: Correct. Also $x = 0 \cdot x^0 + 1 \cdot x^1 + 0 \cdot x^2 + 0 \cdot x^3 +...$ is the generating function for number of trees with a single vertex. I.e. there is only one such tree. You can create a bijection between rooted trees (with deg of root $k$) with unions of a single vertex with a forest of $k$ rooted trees.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Substitute $u=-y$ then 
$-ue^{u}=x \implies ue^u=-x$, hence $u=W(-x)$, in which $W$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Use [Lagranges inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to derive its Taylor series. Or simply look it up on the wiki page under asymptotic expansions. Note, that this equality is only true in the region of convergence.

Comment: Yeah, Lambert is noted in the comments. I haven't been able to find anywhere that the Lambert function has the Taylor series that I've written above...

Comment: Search for asymptotic expansions in the Wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: Wikipedia gives the Taylor series above for Lambert, but doesn't prove it. @SamT

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The Taylor series can be obtained by the Lagrange inversion theorem, the link is in my answer. The page also contains the derivation.

Comment: Yes,  I've just seen the part. The bit that I was missing was to do with the alternating signs on the Wiki page -- but of course, the answer is $y = -W(-x)$, so the signs cancel out nicely. \\ Working out those coefficients would be a nightmare though!

Answer (score 1):

Idea (not completely worked out, but too long for a comment):

- When $x=0$, $y=0$ because exponentials are never zero.
- Using implicit differentiation, $\left(e^{-y}-ye^{-y}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=1$ using implicit differentiation.  Since $y=0$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=1$.
- Using implicit differentiation again, we have 
  $$
  \left(-2e^{-y}+ye^{-y}\right)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+\left(e^{-y}-ye^{-y}\right)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0
  $$
  Substituting in our known values, you get $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2$.

Observe that when these are plugged into the Taylor expansion for $y$ (dividing by $k!$), you get the first few terms in your formula.  There's a lot of structure in these implicit derivatives, you should be able to get some sort of recurrence to explicitly solve.

Comment: Yeah, so differentiating twice isn't a bad shout: it means we can cancel the exponentials. However, I don't see how you deduce $y''(x) = 2$. You have this nasty $(dy/dx)^2$ term in there. I'll have a little more of a think...

Comment: $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ is the square of the first derivative, which we know is $1$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're looking for the Taylor expansion about $0$, and hence are considering $y'(0)$. I see. I guess doing this way is just a special case of the Lagrange inversion for this particular situation.