# Apparent Contradiction by WolframAlpha in Calcuation of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{k-1} e^{-k} / k!$

Tags: proof-verification, summation, fake-proofs

Consider the infinite sum
$$S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1} e^{-k}}{k!}.$$
Note that a basic version of [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) says that $k! \ge (k/e)^k \sqrt{2\pi k}$, and this tells us that
$$S_N = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^{k-1} e^{-k}}{k!} \le \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k^{k-1} e^{-k}}{k^k e^{-k} \sqrt{2\pi k}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{k=1}^N k^{-3/2},$$
and so $S_N \to S$ with $S$ a convergent series. Moreover, a [stronger form of Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) says that $k! \ge (k/e)^k \sqrt{2\pi k} e^{1/(12k + 1)}$. Plugging this in similarly gives
$$S \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-3/2} e^{-1/(12k+1)}.$$

WolframAlpha tells us [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%7Bk%3D1%20to%20infinity%7D%20%7Bk%5E%28-3%2F2%29%20%20e%5E%28-1%2F%2812k%2B1%29%29%7D%20%2F%20sqrt%282*pi%29) that this sum has numerical value approximately $0.95$, and specifically $S<1$. However, when asking WolframAlpha what $S$ is directly [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%7Bk%3D1%20to%20infinity%7D%20%7Bk%5E%28k-1%29%20e%5E%28-k%29%20%2F%20k!%7D), it says that $S = 1$.

As far as I can see, these two claims by WolframAlpha cannot be consistent. That is, unless I've made a mistake somewhere... Note that I *haven't* used an approximation for all $k$ which is only valid for large $k$: Wikipedia claims (via [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2308012?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) that the above stronger form holds for all positive integers $k$, not just sufficiently large ones.

If someone could enlighten me, I'd be most appreciative!

---

Note that [this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174513/show-y-sum-k-1-infty-frackk-1k-xk-satisfies-ye-y-x) along with the fact that $z \mapsto z e^{-z}$ is uniquely maximised at $z = 1$ tells us that $S = 1$. Indeed, taking $x = 1/e$ there gives us that $S$ satisfies $S e^{-S} = e^{-1}$, and the only $S$ satisfying this is $S = 1$, by the maximisation property mentioned above.

Thus it does appear that WolframAlpha is getting stung by rounding rounding errors. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Comment: Interestingly: [Mathematica gets it right](https://ibb.co/mvdPTv), and so does [Wolfram.Alpha (numerical approximation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BSum%5Bk%5E(-3%2F2)+E%5E(-1%2F(12+k+%2B+1))%2FSqrt%5B2*Pi%5D,+%7Bk,+1,+Infinity%7D%5D%5D). But without this explicit request for a numerical approximation, [it fails](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk%5E(-3%2F2)+E%5E(-1%2F(12+k+%2B+1))%2FSqrt%5B2*Pi%5D,+%7Bk,+1,+Infinity%7D%5D)

Comment: That is interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original sum is exactly 1.  The numeric approximation of the last sum in your question is actually $$1.0017976085327493751120130443778945039608311925192\ldots,$$ which is greater than $1$, so that particular input was not evaluated properly.

I leave it as an exercise to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1} e^{-k}}{k!} = 1.$$

Incidentally, the sum arising from the coarser form of Stirling's approximation is $\zeta(3/2)/\sqrt{2\pi} \approx 1.04219$.

Comment: I did wonder if it was just a numerical issue with Wolfram, and so I supposed that the $=1$ would be correct. My follow up question was going to be "how do I show it's equal to $1$". (Of course, I'd had a think about this: if I could show analytically that $S = 1$, then this tells me Wolfram has it wrong.) And yeah, I did notice it's the $\zeta$ function, which I got WA to evaluate and give me $>1$.

Comment: Could you give me a **hint** for how to show the sum is $1$? A **hint**, not a full solution! :)

Comment: Lambert's W function has series $$W(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\,k^{k-1}}{k!}x^k$$So, in terms of a series, what is $-W(-1/e)=1$?  The series for $W$ can be obtained using [Lagrange's Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Comment: Yeah, I know about the Lagrange Inversion theorem from a previous question -- a big mess! However, your pointing that our has made me realise that actually setting $x = e^{-1}$ in this question [1] says that $S e^{-S} = e^{-1}$, and moreover $f(z) := z e^{-z}$ is maximised exclusively at $z = 1$, so we must have $S = 1$.

Comment: [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174513/show-y-sum-k-1-infty-frackk-1k-xk-satisfies-ye-y-x

Answer (score 2):

Lambert's W function has series $$W(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\,k^{k-1}}{k!}x^k \tag 1$$

which has radius of convergence $1/e$.  The series in $(1)$ can be obtained using [Lagrange's Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Since we have $-W(-1/e)=1$, then from $(1)$ we see that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\,k^{k-1}}{k!}\left(-\frac1e\right)^k=1$$

from which we recover the identity

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{k-1}e^{-k}}{k!}=1$$

Comment: Just posted a response to your comment on the other answer! I guess the point is that we have to show $W(-1/e) = -1$, but that's fairly easy, as I did in the comment mentioned.

Comment: @SamT I like your comment!  The previous question and this one are obviously intimately linked.  You might consider referencing them.